# Radio button click

Tags: jquery

I have an html code

```
<s:radio list="#{'0':'Renew','1':'Upgrade'}"
                    name="schemeChangeType" cssClass="radio-connection"
                    id="schemeChangeType" />
```

I need to invoke the click function of this radio button. how?

Comment: @Sreevidya Aravind There are many reference which you can find.. So before asking such questions try something on your own. If you find issue then post your question. Don't simply ask how ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try a css class to invoke the change event. Like

$('.radio-connection').change(function(){

});

hope that it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#schemeChangeType').trigger('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[id$=schemeChangeType]').trigger('click')
```

You seem to be using `jsf` as front-end technology and `jsf` concatenates the `id` of the form and the `id` of the component itself (i.e. `myformid:myradioid`)

The above css selector will find a component that is of type `input` and whose `id` **ends** with `schemeChangeType`

Comment: using structs. I have did it . I added a css class and using that I invoked the change event. Anyway thank you.